# Linux : Set Custom theme for CentOS6

Tags: linux

I am using CentOS6.I wanted to set a custom theme for my system.Is there any website related to this? .I tried with GNOME but most of the themes are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gtk themes then use gtk-chtheme

[Please visit this link](http://pkgs.org/download/gtk-chtheme)

Comment: @suganya if you have accepted the answer, please considering upvoting.